# MongoDB: Understanding cursors and there usage

Tags: mongodb

I am Just a starter to mongo DB. While going through mongoDB documents, I found out few statements, The statements are given below

```
var store_test2 = db.test2.find();
var store_test2_1= store_test2.hasNext() ? store_test2.next(): null;
print(store_test2_1.friends);
```

I've few question from the above code.

1. What is ? in the above code and why my code wont run without specifying it?
2. The store_test2 stores the documents that is returned from collection test2. 
   Test2 collection has many documents. The documents present inside the collection have 
   a key or attribute called friends. I want to print the values of friends for of all
   the documents.

   I am able to achieve the requirement by using functions .
   But How do I achieve the same by using similar code given above?

   for example I have 5 documents each having attribute friends as 34,344,54,32,444.
   My output should look like

   34

   344

   54

   32

   444

   The above code would give me output for only one document's attribute "friends" i.e 34.
3. Can anybody please suggest me some links in which I can find information on

   mongoDB background jobs.

   How read and write happens.

   Cluster behavior.

   Primary and secondary node behavior .

   Whole Architecture of mongoDB.

Comment: there is a lot of questions here, some which can be gotten from a google search, normally it goes Google and then if you cannot find the answer there you ask here

Answer (score 0):

### 1.What is ? in the above code

`?` and `:` are the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It is a shorthand for if...else in assignments. The long form of that line would be:

```
var store_test2_1;
if (store_test2.hasNext()) {
    store_test2_1 = store_test2.next();
} else {
   store_test2_1 = null;
}
```

### 2. I want to print the values of friends for all of the documents.

A MongoDB cursor works like an iterator. You can use the method .next() to retrieve more documents as long as .hasNext() returns true. You can do this with a while-loop:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    var document = cursor.next();
    print(document.friends);
}
```

### 3.Can anybody please suggest me some links

Stackoverflow is straving to become a knowledge base, not a link collection, so please don't ask for links. Ask specific questions and we will try to answer them.

That being said, all these topics are described in [the MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/). When you have specific questions, feel free to ask them as new questions.